# problem was to get 'n' digit number and print each digit separated by a space. What might be the problem?

Tags: python, printing, int, integer

I tried the following code but it gives correct answer if number of digits is less than 16. Like if I input `number=111000111000111`, it gives correct answer but if `number=111000111000111000`, it gives incorrect answers.

```
print("Enter a number of any length")
a=int(input())
b=str(a)
x=len(b)
print(b)
print(x)
for b in b:
     if x<0:
         break
     print(int(a/pow(10,x-1))%10,end=" ")
     x=x-1
```

Correct output:

```
Enter a number of any length
111000111000
111000111000
12
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Wrong output if number of digits > 16:

```
Enter a number of any length
123456789999900987654321 #input
123456789999900987654321 #converted string
24                       #length of string
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 0 8 2 2 0 6 4 4 6 #output
```

Comment: If you have the number as a string, why don't you just write the characters in the loop, instead of operating on the `a` and powers?

Comment: Just: `for char in b: print(char, end=" ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about size of integer. You can achieve your purpose with using following code:

```
print("Enter a number of any length")
num = input("Enter a number of any length: ")
print("len of input {}".format(len(num)))
print(' '.join(num))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use `/`, which brings floating point inaccuracy into the game. Use `//` for integer division and you'll get the correct output.

Anyway, another way:

```
>>> number = 123456789999900987654321
>>> print(*str(number))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Or, since you have the user input the number as a string, no need to convert to int and back to string:

```
>>> print(*input())
123456789999900987654321
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 9 9 9 0 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: The explanation for the solution here is that `print` displays spaces between comma-separated variable parameters (args). `*` operator separates each character from the iterable string into each index in the args list. Great solution, but if you need to, say, return a value from a function or pass a unit test, this isn't going to help a whole lot with that use case.